# Is it possible to determine specific digits of 64 bit number in C

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, chess

I'm trying to make a chess engine. I've done some reading and it seems like using a 64 bit number to represent the board is the way to go. However I'm a little confused, it seems that there's no easy way to write a number in binary, and I also can't find a way to select a digit in a number. For example if I do

```
    int aNum = 356;
    b = aNum[1];
```

Is there a way to do this so that I can set b equal to 5? In the program it'd be a binary number like 1001010101, and I'd like to find out where all of the 1s are when I go through there. For example if I have a rook and I'm looking for possible moves to the right, I would have it iterate through digits until it finds a 1.

Hopefully that was easy to understand, thank you!

---

The issue was a fundamental misunderstanding of why 64 bit numbers are used in chess engines. In reality the advantage is that if you want to check for items on squares you could do something like `boardRep & 1` would check for an element on the first square of the board.

Comment: I'm not sure a 64-bit number makes sense.  Each square can contain any of six pieces (in either colour), or be empty.  What would each binary digit represent?

Comment: "iterate through digits until it finds a 1" - that's fairly simple, using a couple of bit-wise operations (e.g., `>>` and `|`).

Comment: 64bit number to represent a board is not even enough to represent the checkers.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You would have several numbers. For example 1 64 bit num for all pieces on board, one for all of white's pieces and one for all of blacks, and one for each type of piece. My understanding is that it'd make it more efficient when making the AI, since it will be able to do the calculations faster.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm going to go try to read up on bitwise, do you mind if I come back and ask you if I have any questions?

Comment: I really suggest you to forget about these micro-optimizations and go for a representation which is making sense. Such as 8x8 array holding numbers representing the pieces. Perhaps something more sophisticated.

Comment: To my knowledge, [bitboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard) are definitely a thing in chess programming. You may find this [chess programming website](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/) a useful resource.

Comment: I'd forget those bitboards for the moment. Make your chess program work, and once it plays decently, then you can still optimize your code and worry about bitboards.

Comment: The power of bitboards comes from *not* iterating over the bits. The whole point is enabling tricks that mostly avoid such loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch a specific digit in the decimal representation of a 64-bit number (which is *not* what I think you want to do), you first have to create that decimal representation.  The basic recipe would be something like this:

```
uint64_t x = 123456789012345;
char buf[30];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%lld", x);
int digit5 = buf[5] - '0';
printf("digit [5] = %d\n", digit5);
```

This should print `6`.

Bear in mind, though, it's not a 64 *digit* number.  (The largest 64-bit number has 20 decimal digits.)

Perhaps you want to extract *bit* number n.  To do that, you'll need some bitwise operations, perhaps something like this:

```
int bit5 = (x >> 5) & 0x01;
printf("bit 5 = %d\n", bit5);
```

Or if you just want to test the bit, you can do

```
if(x & (1 << 5)) printf("bit 5 is true\n");
```

Or you can precompute some bitmasks:

```
unsigned long long int masks[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, /* ... */ };

if(x & masks[5]) printf("bit 5 is true\n");
```